# jQuery submit button hides the form

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Why isn't this working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#target').submit(function() {
            $('#target').hide();
            return false;
        });
});
</script>

<form id="target">
   <ul id="myTags"></ul>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitbutton" class="tagsubmit" />            
</form>
```

Whenever I click the submit button I want to simply hide the form.

Comment: the code works for me!  which browser?

Comment: Sure you don't have a script error elsewhere? That looks correct.

Comment: seems legit (it does work) http://jsfiddle.net/cR4ET/ have you checked the console for errors? have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Hiya, working here: http://jsfiddle.net/KaAAZ/13/ cheers!

Comment: @Joseph jQuery is loaded, I have some other bits of code there, but nothing that looks related. I'm using FF

Comment: Hem, your code works fine for me. I just wrapped it in <head>, <body> and added jquery 1.7.1. I use FF as well (11)

Comment: @Joseph no idea why, but if i change ``$('#target').hide();`` to ``$('.tagsubmit').hide();`` it does hide the button (not the entire form obviously). How can this be?

Comment: you may have another element with the same ID

Comment: @Joseph - oh no :) that was it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks to @Joseph.

Had another form with the same id which caused the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
        $('#target').hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Because the action will get triggered when you click on the #submitbutton. Hope you get what you wanted to do :)

Comment: have you tested his code if it works before making this assumption?

Comment: i know your code works, but have you considered that another error could have been causing his problem? like jQuery not loaded? or a conflicting library? in these case, your solution won't work also.

Comment: @Joseph ya that might be true. I suggested some alternate in case that works for him. Also I will take care hence of the same. Thanks :)

Comment: @SahilGrover lolz you forked what I did mentioned above in my comments :)) ha ha,